# Vue v-for not updating, even with set

Tags: typescript, vue.js, v-for, vue-class-components

I have a `v-for` list that renders the initial state of an array. But when I add items to the array, the rendering is not updated.
Most answers in the docs and here on SO mention you have to use `this.$set` instead of `array.push()`, but in my case that isn't helping.

When calling `addTag("thing")`, "thing" *is* added to the array *and* it is visible in the Vue inspector. It's just the `v-for` that isn't updated.

**template**

```
<span v-for="(tag, index) in project.tags" :key="index">
      {{tag}}    // this renders all the tags that are initially available
</span>
```

**code** (vue typescript class template)

```
export default class Student extends Vue {
    project:Project = {} as Project
    newtag : string = ""

    addTag() {
        // adds to array, but v-for not updating
        this.$set(this.project.tags, this.project.tags.length, this.newtag)

        // adds to array, but v-for not updating
        this.project.tags.push(this.newtag)
    }
}
```

EDIT this code uses the [typescript class component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component)

Comment: why not you put `project` inside `data` ?

Comment: because it uses the typescript class template https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component

Comment: Wow I didn't know about this. thanks

Comment: yeah it's pretty awesome, makes code much more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use $set when you want to add an attribute to an object after initialization, instead of using it here, just init the object with an empty tag array.

Change your code to look like this:

```
export default class Student extends Vue {
   //I'm not a TS expert, so I'm not sure this is the correct way to init
   // a tags array, but you get the point
    project:Project = {tags:[]} as Project
    newtag : string = ""

    addTag() {   
        // adds to array, but v-for not updating
        this.project.tags.push(this.newtag)
    }
}
```

As a side note, if you are planning on changing the list dynamically (adding/removing tags), using the index as a key is not recommended and can lead to unexpected behavior. Better use an id or the tag name if it's unique.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It starts to look a bit weird since I'm using typescript, I have to tell the compiler that my empty array is of the correct type: `project:Project = {tags:[] as string[]} as Project`